# R Shiny bookmarked URL doesn't renderPlot when link used

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use R Shiny to bookmark state into the URL.  The app works OK on first use, and maintains the URL ok, but when I use the URL, or just refresh the browser, the app doesn't show the plot is supposed to show.

The javascript console says:
"Error: util.addPathParams doesn't implement escaping"

It also throws this error:
Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: a.LegacyGlobal.LP_explicit_ignored is not a function. (In 'a.LegacyGlobal.LP_explicit_ignored(document,e)', 'a.LegacyGlobal.LP_explicit_ignored' is undefined)

It appears it doesn't like the text in the url.

I found I could replicate whatever mistake I'm making by taking the "hello shiny" in lesson 1 on rstudio site and adding bookmark code. I marked the edited lines with comments. https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson1/

Here is the code below on shinyapps.io:
https://jackprior.shinyapps.io/shinypractice/

```
#attempt to add bookmarking to rstudio lesson 1 and replicate bug
#https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson1/
library(shiny)
plotmsg =function(txt){return(plot(1:5,main=txt))}  #this is new 
ui <-function(request){ fluidPage(                  #UI wrapped in a function
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30),
      textInput("w","name",value="a plot title"), #this is new
      bookmarkButton()      # This is new
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot"),
      plotOutput("plot"),   # This is new
    )
  )
)
}

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot(plotmsg(input$w)) #this is new
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful[, 2] 
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, enableBookmarking = "url") #this has added parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was the use of "w" as an input parameter.  Shinyapps.io encodes the &w into something it can't evaluate and hangs the reactive in perpetual evaluation.  The use of a different name for the input fixed it.  It seems like a shinyapps.io bug unless the user is supposed to know not to use "w".  I was only using it to minimize the length of the URL.